# Parse this string "20160713161212" to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, string-formatting, strptime

I have `datetime` a string `"20160713161212"`.
It is a `datetime` in string with format `YYYYMMDDHHIISS`
How to parse it to string with format `"07/13/2016 16:12:12"` in Python?

Answer (score 2):

I think that's what you are looking for:

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime('20160713161212', '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
new_dt = dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

For further info you can take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)